# LINQ – Nested (address & city) query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a problem with a project. I’m trying to get a list of companies that are located in a specific country or city.

Table structure:

**Company**

```
CompanyID
CompanyName
etc…
```

**CompanyAddressDetails** (relation table)

```
Company_CompanyID
CorrespondingAddress_AddressID
```

**CorrespondingAddress**:

```
AddressID
StreetName
RegionID
etc…
```

**Region**

```
RegionID
RegionName
RegionRegionTypeID
```

**RegionDetails** (relation table)

```
RegionParent
RegionChild
```

So to find an address in example Stockholm (which has ID 1198 in the Region table), I would do:

```
var addresses = from c in db.CorrespondingAddress select c;
addresses = addresses.Where(s => s.RegionID.Equals(1198));
```

And to find a company in Stockholm I would do:

```
companyModel = from c in db.Company select c;
companyModel =  companyModel.Where(s => s.CorrespondingAddress.Any(x => x.RegionID.Equals(1198)));
```

But now I want to take into account the RegionDetails table (which has a parent, and child, for example: 1 (Sweden) is parent, and 1198 (Stockholm) is child etc)

How can I do to find a company which is located in Sweden, but has the ID 1198 (Stockholm) in its address row?

In plain SQL I would maybe do something like:

```
SELECT CompanyName FROM Company
LEFT JOIN CompanyAddressDetails ON (Company.CompanyID = CompanyAddressDetails.Company_CompanyID)
LEFT JOIN CorrespondingAddress ON (CompanyAddressDetails.CorrespondingAddress_AddressID = CorrespondingAddress.AddressID)
LEFT JOIN Region ON (CorrespondingAddress.RegionID = Region.RegionID)
WHERE CorrespondingAddress IN (SELECT RegionChild FROM RegionDetails WHERE RegionParent = 1)
```

Comment: Do you need to be able to search anywhere within the region hierarchy (e. g. are there only parent and child regions or can children also have children, maybe something like USA parent of Virginia parent of Richmond)?

Comment: It’s not necessary, because in the RegionDetails table every parent have a relationship to its children, so there are no three structures. So USA would have 2 relationships: USA -> Virginia & USA -> Richmond separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there is no model for the details tables (many-to-many relationship tables), I solved it by using this method:

```
companyModel = companyModel.Where(s => s.CorrespondingAddress.Any(x => x.Region.RegionParent.Any(d => d.RegionID == region)));
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the following code can be refactored into one line:

```
companyModel = from c in db.Company select c;
companyModel =  companyModel.Where(s => s.CorrespondingAddress.Any(x => x.RegionID.Equals(1198)));
```

Can't you just nest another `Any`?

```
companyModel = db.Company.Where(s => s.CorrespondingAddress.Any(x => x.Region.Any(r => r.RegionDetails.Any(rd => rd.Parent == 1 && rd.Child == 1198)));
```

**Edit**

Given the following property of `CorrespondingAddress`:

```
public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
```

And assuming `Region` has a property RegionDetails (making Region -> RegionDetails one-to-one):

```
public virtual RegionDetails RegionDetails{ get; set; }
```

The following should work:

```
companyModel = db.Company.Where(s => s.CorrespondingAddress.Any(x => x.Region.RegionDetails.RegionParent == 1 && x.Region.RegionDetails.RegionChild == 1198)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I try that I get the following error:

'Region' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'Region' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you using Code First? Can you post your models? My assumption was your `CorrespondingAddress` entity had a property named `Region`.

Comment: We are using Model First, and looking at the CorrespondingAddress entity code, I see that the only Region property there is, is this line:

public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks for your help, however the Details tables doesn’t have a model because they are just many-to-many relationship tables, so I solved it in a similar way, if you check my post. Thanks again for your help.